# Resource class becomes missing after installing Pikkart.ArSDK

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When creating a new project, I can easily access the `Resource` class inside `Resource.Designer.cs` without error, like this *(this is just the default template, I haven't added any codes at all)*:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace NocturlabsAR_Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "NocturlabsAR_Droid", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

Plus, I can see `Resource` when opening the **IntelliSense**. But after installing the `Pikkart.ArSDK` package in **NuGet**, a short bit after installation, the `Resource` disappears in the **IntelliSense**, and now I'm receiving this error:

> The name `Resource` does not exist in the current context

I just added a package, and now `Resource` can't even be located in the **IntelliSense**. I'm sure the said package is the problem, because when I uninstalled it, it works again.

Tried the following:

- **Clean->Rebuild** = *Error*
- **Deleted `Resource.Designer.cs`, Rebuild, Included the generated `Resource.Designer.cs`, Rebuild again** = *Error*
- **Tried adding a class inside the `Resources` folder just to test whether I can reference something inside** = *I can reference a test class with the same namespace, but I can't still refer the `Resource` class*
- **Tried using `Android.Resource.Layout.Main`** = *Same error, but is now referring to `Main` and not `Resource`*

What else can I do to be able to call the `Resource` class?

***NOTE***: The sample **Pikkart** provides in its [repository](https://github.com/pikkart-support/Pikkart-AR-SDK-LocalPlanarMarker-Xamarin.Android-Sample) is working. It also has the `Pikkart.ArSDK` installed, yet the `Resource` is working fine. I will update the question if other info is needed.

Comment: Please include a [sample project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue. Also, please include your Xamarin version information. Finally, can you check to see "what" your `Resource.Designer.cs` file is doing between builds? For example, after a build with no reference, you should have a couple resources included in this file. When referencing the project, does the project even build? If not, get a [Diagnostic Build Output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) to attach to this question.

Comment: @JonDouglas Actually, that is the whole project *(except of course of the `using`)*. I haven't add any codes at all, just installed a package

Comment: @JonDouglas The weird thing is, sometimes it is okay, but after a while, it will become an error. I already tried the `MSBuild Output`, and rebuilding the project now becomes successful.